# change camera rotation without dragging canvas in Aframe

Tags: aframe

I am playing with Aframe (version 0.8.0) sometime now. I am stuck at one problem, I have been searching for its solution for couple of days but failed thus this question.

My problem is how can I change camera rotation without  having to drag on canvas?

I tried these things but they didn't work:

- camera.setAttribute('rotation', {....})
- camera.object3D.children[0].rotation.x = 0 // some value
- putting camera entity as the child of another entity and changing the rotation of parent entity is not what I am looking for

Any hint would be appreciated, thanks...

Update: this problem occurs only with version 0.8. There is no such error in previous version 0.7.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're milage will vary but you could try:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-rotate-camera-test

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent("rotate", {
        init: function () {
          document.body.onkeyup = (e) => {
            if(e.keyCode == 32){
              this.el.components['look-controls'].yawObject.rotation.y += 1
            }
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried your glitch code, but after few clicks if I drag on canvas, camera rotates around Z axis a little. [In this screenshot it is obvious](https://i.imgur.com/ygaGpd9.png)

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted both look-controls and this functionality. From what I see you'll likely conflict with the look controls component: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/look-controls.js That said, the imperfect way to fix the above code is something like: `this.el.components.camera.camera.parent.rotation.set(0,  45, 0)` but you'll notice the look controls resets the rotation on mouse drag, so you might want to modify your own version of look-controls with an api to hook into the 'pitchObject'. Quick fix ex: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-cam-rotate-drag

Comment: now the only solution I need to try is to look at the source code of look-controls and see if I can find anything there. Thanks a lot. I will accept your answer (or maybe update it) after I look into look-controls.

Comment: Updated the answer to dive deeper into the look-controls component. This could be a way to help you avoid modifying the component. Not the prettiest way but should get you a bit further. There's a small risk that if a-frame updates, renames or removes that property, it could break your code in the future. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-look-rotate

Comment: this seems to work without any side effect. I will report if I face any problem. thanks